# Cordova/Phonegap - How to merge two audio files into one file

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build, devextreme

I am using Media API of Cordova to record and play Audio files,
What I want now is that whenever I record an audio file then it must merge to previous audio file if previous audio file exist or if it does not exist then it must create as a new file.

I am not getting any solution to it, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should answer your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25040735/phonegap-mixing-audio-files

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Lukesmith, the solution given by you is of HTML5 WebAPI and I want solution for Cordova Media API. If the solution given by you is correct then I am not able to decide how to use it in context of Media API