# How do I load in multiple Processing (.pde) files into an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, processing

So I know that with JS and a lot of JS frameworks you can simply do the following to put your sketch into html:

```
<script src="FirstScript.js"></script>
<script src="SecondScript.js"></script>
```

and so on.

But in Processing, you do the following:

```
<canvas id="your-id-here" data-processing-sources="Code.pde"></canvas>
```

Since it is inside the canvas, you can't add multiple files. I have looked around and haven't found a solution.

If it matters, I am trying to link a sound file. How can I do this?

Also, I know I could just switch over to some other JS framework, like p5, but I would rather stay in Processing.

Comment: You can load the audio file at an `<audio>` element or `AudioContext()` and use `canvas.captureStream()`; see [MediaStream Capture Canvas and Audio Simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302814/mediastream-capture-canvas-and-audio-simultaneously), [Is it possible to mix multiple audio files on top of each other preferably with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570114/is-it-possible-to-mix-multiple-audio-files-on-top-of-each-other-preferably-with)

Answer (score 0):

In order to load multiple pde files in a webpage by using processing.js library, you can simply mention all the files inside the `data-processing-sources` tag.

e.g.
`<canvas id="your-id-here" data-processing-sources="file1.pde file2.pde"></canvas>`

For playing sounds in processing.js you can use a java-to-javascript binding workaround:

https://funprogramming.org/141-Processing-js-with-sound-audio-I.html
https://funprogramming.org/142-Processing-js-with-sound-audio-II.html