# how we can Play Audio with text highlight word by word in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I am working on an Angular JS project , I am newbie in this technology . I have received an assignment from my boss .

> Assignment is :

1 . There is a html file with the text "This is a Burger" .

2 . I have a Audio(.mp3) file with the sound "This is a Burger" .

this is javascript example [Preload mp3 file in queue to avoid any delay in playing the next file in queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049639/preload-mp3-file-in-queue-to-avoid-any-delay-in-playing-the-next-file-in-queue)

> What I want :

When Audio play then the text "This is Burger" should high light word by word .

Here is what I have done to achieve above task .

> json

```
{

    "config":{
        "shuffleQuestions": true,
        "showPager": false,
        "allowBack": true,
        "autoMove": true
    },
    "questions": [{
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "This is a burger.1",  
        "Image": "assets/quiz/burgur.jpg", 
        "QuestionAudio":"assets/quiz/audio.mp3",
        "QuestionAudiodelay":"100",
        "QuestionAudioTimeline":"0.07,1.04,1.8,2.29,3.19", 
        "Options": [{ "Id": 1, "OptionsId": 1, "Name": "This is a burger.1", "IsAnswer": true }],
        "QuestionType": { "Id": 1, "Name": "Multiple Choice", "IsActive": true } }]}
```

> html

```
<div id="quiz"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"><h1 class="left">{{quiz.name}}</h1><hr /></div>
    </div> 
    <div ng-show="mode=='quiz'">
        <div ng-repeat="question in filteredQuestions"> 
            <div class="row">
               <h2>{{currentPage}}.</h2>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="card col-md-6"> 
                      <div class="flex-center">
                          <div class="card-block">  
                            <img id="{{question.Id}}" class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{question.Image}}" style="width: 500px;">          
                        </div>     
                    </div>  
                </div>

            <div class="row text-left options">
                <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="option in question.Options">
                    <div class="option"> 

                            <p id="{{option.Id}}"  ng-bind-html="allAnswerWithSpan"> </p>

                    </div> 
                </div> 
                  <p id="optionAnswer"> </p>
                <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat="option in question.Options" >
                    <div class="option"> 
                        <button  ng-click="playAudio()" class="btn btn-default">Play</button> 
                    </div>
                <audio id="myAudio" style="display: block !important;">
                <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
                </audio>
                <img  id="playaudio"  style="cursor:pointer;width: 25px;height: 25px; display:none;" src='images/audio_joshi.png'/>   
               </div> 

            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="quizNav">
            <div> 
                <button class="btn btn-default"   ng-hide="IsHidden"   ng-click="NextQuiz(currentPage - 1);">Prev</button> 
                <button id="Next" class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="IsVisible" ng-click="NextQuiz(currentPage + 1);">Next</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-hide="IsHidden"  ng-click="onSubmit();" >Submit</button>  
            </div>
            <br /> 
        </div>
    </div> 

    <hr /> 
</div>
```

> js

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('quizApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
// Routing has been added to keep flexibility in mind. This will be used in future.
angular.module('quizApp').config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) { 
      var routes = [
          {
              url: '/home',
              template: 'templates/quiz.html',
              controller: 'quizCtrl'
          } 
      ];

      routes.forEach(function (r, index) {
          $routeProvider.when(r.url, { templateUrl: r.template, controller: r.controller });
      }); 
      $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
       //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
var quizCtrl = function ($scope, $http, helper) {
    $scope.quizName = 'assets/quiz.json'; 
    $scope.arrQuestion=[];  $scope.arrOptionsId=[]; $scope.addanswer=[];
    $scope.allarray =[]; 
    // Others are work in progress.
    $scope.defaultConfig = {
        'allowBack': true,
        'allowReview': true,
        'autoMove': false,  // if true, it will move to next question automatically when answered.
        'duration': 0,    // indicates the time in which quiz needs to be completed. post that, quiz will be automatically submitted. 0 means unlimited.
        'pageSize': 1,
        'requiredAll': false,  // indicates if you must answer all the questions before submitting.
        'richText': false,
        'shuffleQuestions': false,
        'shuffleOptions': false,
        'showClock': false,
        'showPager': true,
        'theme': 'block'
    } 

     $scope.IsVisible = true;
     $scope.IsHidden = true;
     $scope.IsHidden = $scope.IsHidden ? true : true;
    $scope.NextQuiz = function (index) {
        if (index > 0 && index <= $scope.totalItems) {
            $scope.currentPage = index; 
            $scope.mode = 'quiz';
        } 
         if(index==$scope.totalItems){
             $scope.IsHidden = false;
             $scope.IsVisible = $scope.IsVisible ? false : true;
        }   $scope.qIndex++;

    }


    $scope.onClick = function (question, option) {
        if (question.QuestionTypeId == 1) {
            question.Options.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
                if (element.Id != option.Id) {
                    element.Selected = false;
                    question.Answered = element.Id;
                }
            });  
        } 

        if ($scope.config.autoMove == true && $scope.currentPage < $scope.totalItems)
            $scope.currentPage++;

    } 
    $scope.onSubmit = function () {  
        var answers = [];
       /*  $scope.questions.forEach(function (q, index) { //console.log(answers.push({'QuizId': $scope.quiz.Id, 'QuestionId': q.Id, 'Answered': q.Answered}));
            answers.push({ 'QuizId': $scope.quiz.Id, 'QuestionId': q.Id, 'Answered': q.Answered });
        }); */
        // Post your data to the server here. answers contains the questionId and the users' answer.
        //$http.post('api/Quiz/Submit', answers).success(function (data, status) {
        //    alert(data);
        //});

        $scope.mode = 'result';
    } 
    $scope.pageCount = function () {  
        return Math.ceil($scope.questions.length / $scope.itemsPerPage);
    };

    //If you wish, you may create a separate factory or service to call loadQuiz. To keep things simple, i have kept it within controller.
    $scope.loadQuiz = function (file) {  
        $http.get(file)
         .then(function (res) {
            // $scope.quiz = res.data.quiz; console.log($scope.quiz.name);
             $scope.config = helper.extend({}, $scope.defaultConfig, res.data.config); 
             $scope.questions = $scope.config.shuffleQuestions ? helper.shuffle(res.data.questions) : res.data.questions; 
             $scope.totalItems = $scope.questions.length;  
             $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.config.pageSize;
             $scope.currentPage = 1;
             $scope.currentquestion=1;
             $scope.mode = 'quiz'; 
             if($scope.config.shuffleOptions)
                $scope.shuffleOptions();
             $scope.$watch('currentPage + itemsPerPage', function () {
                 var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
                   end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage; 
                 $scope.filteredQuestions = $scope.questions.slice(begin, end);
             }); 
               $scope.questions.forEach(function (question,key){  
                      $scope.arrAnswer= question.Options[0].Name; $scope.arrOptionsId= question.Options[0].Id;  
                      $scope.arraudio= question.QuestionAudio;   
                      $scope.arraudiodelay= question.QuestionAudiodelay;  
                      $scope.arraudiotimeline= question.QuestionAudioTimeline; 
                      $scope.allarray=[$scope.arrAnswer,$scope.arraudio,$scope.arraudiodelay,$scope.arraudiotimeline];
                      $scope.arrQuestion.push($scope.allarray);   

                });   
                if($scope.currentPage==1)
                {   
                 // console.log($scope.arrQuestion);
                  $scope.qIndex = 0;
                  $scope.audioplay();
                }

         });
 } 
    $scope.audioplay=function(){
         var qIndex = $scope.qIndex; 
             $scope.QuestionAnswer=$scope.arrQuestion[qIndex][0];
             $scope.QuestionAudio=$scope.arrQuestion[qIndex][1];
             $scope.QuestionAudiodelay=$scope.arrQuestion[qIndex][2]; 
             $scope.Questionaudiotimeline=$scope.arrQuestion[qIndex][3];
             //console.log($scope.QuestionAnswer); console.log($scope.QuestionAudio);
             //console.log($scope.QuestionAudiodelay);
             console.log($scope.arrOptionsId);

      $scope.QuestionAnswerArray = $scope.QuestionAnswer.split(' '); //alert($scope.QuestionAnswerArray.length);
      $scope.allAnswerWithSpan = {}; 
        for (var i = 0; i <$scope.QuestionAnswerArray.length; i++) {
                $scope.addanswer[i] = '<span>' +$scope.QuestionAnswerArray[i]+ '</span>'; 
                // console.log($scope.addanswer);
          }            
           $scope.allAnswerWithSpan = $scope.addanswer.join(" ");

         var audio =new Audio($scope.QuestionAudio);
         audio.play();
           audio[0].onended = function() {
                audioIndex += 1;
                playAudio(audioIndex); 
            }; 
  }
      $scope.playAudio=function(index){   
        /* $("p > span").removeClass("playing");
        $("#myAudio")[0].src = $scope.QuestionAudio[index];  
        $("#myAudio")[0].play();
        $("p > span:nth-child(" + (index + 1) + ")").addClass("playing"); */
    } 
    $scope.shuffleOptions = function(){
        $scope.questions.forEach(function (question) {
           question.Options = helper.shuffle(question.Options);
        });
    } 
    $scope.loadQuiz($scope.quizName);  
} 
quizCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'helperService'];
app.controller('quizCtrl', quizCtrl);
```

Comment: There's a lot of code in this question (Which is fine), but please explain what it does so we can understand it better. Describe the issue with the **relevant part** in the code. Also show us the relevant view and describe the desired result based on the code you've posted (You can use a working snippet by clicking on the `{}` button when you [edit] your question)

Comment: hi i have edit the code . can you check this  code  i need  play audio and text  high light  word by word according this js  example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049639/preload-mp3-file-in-queue-to-avoid-any-delay-in-playing-the-next-file-in-queue