# Most sensible way of preloading a batch of audio files

Tags: javascript, html, preload

For my application, I need to pre-load numerous audio files (about 20).

I am aware that I could use a series of `<audio>` tags with the `preload` attribute, but having loads of these doesn't seem to be the most orderly approach.

Any suggestions that would enable a single audio player to be used would be gratefully received.

Comment: How do you plan on playing these files?  Are you wanting to use a single audio tag for all of them?  Also are they all the same audio, but just a different type? Or is it something like 20 different songs?

Comment: I plan to use a single audio tag. Each audio clip is different. They are short 1-2 second voice clips of a single spoken word. I plan to play them by using `$('.audioPlayer').trigger('play');` in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fetch()` and `Promise.all()` with `.map()` or a `for..of` loop and `Promise` constructor to request the media resources as `Blob` or `ArrayBuffer` and render playback at a single `<audio>` node using `MediaSource` or simply setting `src` of `<audio>` node to next `Blob` representation of file by passing `Blob` to `URL.createObjectURL()` to create a `Blob URL`.

Comment: Could you add a little bit more explanation please? I've never worked with Blob, ArrayBuffer or MediaSource before.

Comment: @Joel See [Preload mp3 file in queue to avoid any delay in playing the next file in queue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42049639/), [How to use Blob URL, MediaSource or other methods to play concatenated Blobs of media fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45217962/), [How to create or convert text to audio at chromium browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44346410/)

Comment: `let mediaResources = Promise.all(["media1.ext", "media2.ext", ].map(url => fetch(url).then(response => response.blob()))).then(blobs => {console.log(blobs)//do stuff with media resources as Blobs}).catch(err => console.error(err))`