# Javascript - Seek audio to certain position when at exact position in audio track

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, audiocontext

Scenario:

1. Audio starts playing from **0:00**. At exactly **0:05**, the track skips forwards to **0:30**.
2. The track immediately starts playing at **0:30**, and at exactly **0:35**, the track skips backwards to **0:05** and plays the rest of the audio file

Summary: **Play: 0:00 to 0.05**, **Skip: 0:05 to 0:30**, **Play: 0:30 to 0:35**, **Skip: 0:35 to 0:05**, **Play: 0.05 to END**

The real problem comes when there is the need for a immediate and seamless skip. For example, `setTimeout` is [very inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097421/what-is-the-reason-javascript-settimeout-is-so-inaccurate) and drifts meaning it cannot be used in this case.

I have tried to use the Web Audio API to accomplish this, but I'm still unable to get an immediate transition. I'm currently scheduling segments of a loaded song using `AudioBufferSourceNode.start(when, offset, duration);`, initially passing in `(0 [when], 0 [offset], 0:05 [duration])` for the example above. After this, I'm still using `setTimeout` to call the same function to run just short of **0:30** and scheduling something like `(0 [when] + 0:05 [previous duration], 0:30 [offset], 0:05 [duration])`.

**Example of this**

```js
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext,
    audioCtx     = new AudioContext();
    
var skipQueue = [0, 5, 30, 35, 5];
    
// getSong(); // load in the preview song (https://audiojungle.net/item/inspiring/9325839?s_rank=1)

playSound(0, 0);

function getSong() {
    console.log("Loading song...");

    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // request.open('GET', "https://preview.s3.envato.com/files/230851789/preview.mp3?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D20382637_uplifting-cinematic-epic_by_jwaldenmusic_preview.mp3&Expires=1501966849&Signature=HUMfPw3b4ap13cyrc0ZrNNumb0s4AXr7eKHezyIR-rU845u65oQpxjmZDl8AUZU7cR1KuQGV4TLkQ~egPt5hCiw7SUBRApXw3nnrRdtf~M6PXbNqVYhrhfNq4Y~MgvZdd1NEetv2rCjhirLw4OIhkiC2xH2jvbN6mggnhNnw8ZemBzDH3stCVDTEPGuRgUJrwLwsgBHmy5D2Ef0It~oN8LGG~O~LFB5MGHHmRSjejhjnrfSngWNF9SPI3qn7hOE6WDvcEbNe2vBm5TvEx2OTSlYQc1472rrkGDcxzOHGu9jLEizL-sSiV61uVAp5wqKxd2xNBcsUn3EXXnjMIAmUIQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIEEC7ZU2JC6FKENA", true); // free preview from envato
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    request.onload = function() {
        var audioData = request.response;

        audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
            audioBuffer = buffer;

            console.log("Ready to play!");
            
            playSong()
        }, function(e) {
            "Error with decoding audio data" + e.err
        });
    }

    request.send();
}


function playSound(previousPlay, nextPlay) {
    // source        = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    // source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    // source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    
    skipQueue.shift();

    var duration = Math.abs(skipQueue[0] - previousPlay);

    // source.start(nextPlay, previousPlay, duration);
    
    console.log("Running: source.start(" + nextPlay + ", " + previousPlay + ", " + duration + ")");
    console.log("Current Time: " + previousPlay);
    console.log("Next Play in: " + duration + " (Skipping from " + skipQueue[0] + " to " + skipQueue[1] + ")");

    if (skipQueue.length > 1) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          playSound(skipQueue[0], nextPlay + duration);
      }, 1000 * duration - 50); // take 50ms off for drift that'll be corrected in scheduling
    }
}
```

```html
<strong>Expected:</strong><br />
Play: 0:00 to 0.05, Skip: 0:05 to 0:30, Play: 0:30 to 0:35, Skip: 0:35 to 0:05, Play: 0.05 to END
```

I can't get this simplified down example 100% working, but you can see what my attempt is in the console. I've also commented out code since StackOverflow doesn't support AJAX.

I'm open to using any other API or method that you have in mind!

Comment: a working fiddle? perhaps? Just to play with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't ever show when you actually call start() on an AudioBufferSourceNode, so I can't explicitly debug.  But in short, you need to schedule the stops and starts AHEAD of when they need to happen, not try to "swap" the active sound playing in a setTimeout callback (or try to get them to align once the sound has stopped playing).

For example, you'd do something like:

```
var bs1 = audioCtx.createBufferSourceNode();
var bs2 = audioCtx.createBufferSourceNode();
var bs3 = audioCtx.createBufferSourceNode();
var now = audioCtx.currentTime + 0.020; // add 20ms for scheduling slop

bs1.buffer = audioBuffer;
bs1.connect( audioCtx.destination );
bs2.buffer = audioBuffer;
bs2.connect( audioCtx.destination );
bs3.buffer = audioBuffer;
bs3.connect( audioCtx.destination );
bs1.start( now, 0, 5 );  // time, offset, duration
bs2.start( now+5, 30, 5 );
bs3.start( now+10, 5 );   // no duration; play to end
```

If you want to cancel this playing, you'll have to disconnect the buffersource nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah something like this will work I think but I'll need to test it first. What's the 20ms for? In the case where there is infinitely many queued skips, what's the best way for going about this?

Comment: The 20ms (or more) is because you need to schedule things in the WebAudio timeline BEFORE they should actually happen.  cf A Tale of Two clocks: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue in this will be the accuracy in time and shifting seamlessly from 0:05 to 0:30 and back from 0:35 to 0:05.

I think you should create two different audio sources. Start one from 0:00 and seek the other one at 0:30 but pause it as soon as it starts playing using events.

Then track time using the ontimeupdate event and check it if it is 5 then pause the current and start the second which should now be buffered and when it reaches to 0:35 pause it and start the first one and let it play till the audio finishes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've already tried this and dont think it will meet the requirements of precision and immediately seeking through the track. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12325960/2957677

Answer (score 1):

> Play: 0:00 to 0.05, Skip: 0:05 to 0:30, Play: 0:30 to 0:35, Skip: 0:35
>   to 0:05, Play: 0.05 to END

You can use [Media Fragments URI](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/) and `pause` event to render exact media playback in sequence. If necessary pass the `HTMLMediaElement` to [`AudioContext.createMediaElementSource()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource)

```js
const audio = document.querySelector("audio");

const mediaURL = "https://ia600305.us.archive.org/30/items/return_201605/return.mp3";

const timeSlices = ["#t=0,5", "#t=30,35", "#t=5"];
let index = 0;
audio.onpause = e => {
  if (index < timeSlices.length) {
    audio.src = `${mediaURL}${timeSlices[index++]}`
  } else {
    console.log("Media fragments playlist completed");
  }
}
audio.ontimeupdate = e => console.log(Math.ceil(audio.currentTime));
audio.oncanplay = e => audio.play();
audio.src = `${mediaURL}${timeSlices[index++]}`;
```

```html
<audio controls></audio>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't know you could do it like this. However, in the example the transition is not an "immediate and seamless skip". I'm going to be transitioning seemlessly throughout a song so it is important that the transition happens at a very precise point, but using `ontimeupdate` cannot provide enough precision (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12325960/2957677)

Comment: @TobyMellor `timeupdate` event was used only to display the accurate `.currentTime` of the media playback. The `pause` event handler is where next media frament is set at `.src` of `<audio>` element. You can use `.linearRampToValueAtTime()` to mix the media fragments together; not sure about "seamless", though you can configure the settings in the manner that you expect, see [Web audio api, stop sound gracefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511541/web-audio-api-stop-sound-gracefully)

Comment: @TobyMellor See also [HTML5 audio streaming: precisely measure latency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768375/html5-audio-streaming-precisely-measure-latency)