# Mixing multiple audio files using Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, arraybuffer

I want to combine audio files layered on top of each other with a specific range of an audio file with specific starting time.

1. I want to combine audio files layered on top of each other (I was able to do this with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40570114/is-it-possible-to-mix-multiple-audio-files-on-top-of-each-other-preferably-with))
2. Combine audio files width specific starting time.
3. Combine audio files with specific range of an audio.

I need help for #2 and #3.
Does anyone know how to do it?

PS, if there’re any libraries that can do this, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked answer uses `AudioBufferSourceNode`s with an `OfflineAudioContext` to mix the audio files (or `AudioBuffer`s to be more precise). You can use there [`start()`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audiobuffersourcenode-start) and [`stop()`](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audioscheduledsourcenode-stop) methods of that `AudioBufferSourceNode`s to schedule the files at the desired time and to make them stop earlier.

```
source.start(1, 2, 3);
```

The code above will for example start the `source` after 1 second with of an offset of 2 seconds and will play it for 3 seconds. This does of course only work if the provided `AudioBuffer` is at least 5 seconds long.

Comment: Is there a way to change the volume of a track?

Comment: Sure, that can be done by piping the signal through a GainNode. https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/GainNode